# How to upload an archive via Graph API for instant game?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We try to upload archive to web hosting per [doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/instant-games/test-publish-share/#package-your-game-into-a-single--zip-file)

```
curl -X POST https://graph-video.facebook.com/{App ID}/assets 
  -F 'access_token={ASSET UPLOAD ACCESS TOKEN}' 
  -F 'type=BUNDLE' 
  -F 'asset=@./{YOUR GAME}.zip' 
  -F 'comment=Graph API upload'
```

and get the upload access token by this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#apptokens)

[image]

```
curl -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token
  ?client_id={your-app-id}
  &client_secret={your-app-secret}
  &grant_type=client_credentials"
```

However, we got the following error

```
{"error":{"message":"(#200) Permissions error","type":"OAuthException","code":200,"fbtrace_id":"A8uQbx3l5o5atIQJjaddy"}}
```

Is there anything we are missing? or how to get `ASSET UPLOAD ACCESS TOKEN` correctly?

Comment: _“and get the upload access token by this link”_ - that request gets you a normal app access token, not an asset upload access token. I very much doubt those two are the same, and the documentation for the upload part says explicitly that you should get it from the backend.

Comment: @CBroe, We try to get app access token from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#apptokens or https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname&version=v8.0, both of them are failed. Could you please give us some link about `the backend`?

Comment: I am talking about what it says on the documentation page you linked to.

Comment: @CBroe Sorry for misunderstanding you